# ClickOnce Publish fails and can't clean up

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I am using ClickOnce to publish my application to a virtual server.  Sometimes (and we don't know why) the Publishing of the application freezes.  It will copy some of the files and then about 20 min later will copy one more and so one.  Other times it will work fine.

The problem I have is that when I click Project -> Cancel Build, it will stop the publishing process but it keeps locks on my Debug/app.publish folder.  These locks are not released even when I restart Visual Studio.  If I don't remove those locks (usually by rebooting my machine), and I try to do another normal compile/build, my whole Visual Studio freezes and hangs my whole machine as it gets stuck on those files locks.

Does anyone know why this would happen?  Does anyone know how to remove the file locks on the app.publish folder so I don't have to reboot and get on with my work?

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues where the files it's replacing on the web server get locked or are in use and difficult to overwrite remotely.   I usually from time to time have to remote in to the server to delete them and then try to publish again.   I've seen this on load balancing servers that replicate and the process has caused issues for me.

Comment: to clarify - the files that are locked are files on my own machine because of the build/publish process.  This only happens if I have to cancel the publish process to the server because that process hangs.  My machine is messed up due to a problem on the server and VS not cleaning up after itself.